# How can I slow down UINavigationController's swipe back animation?

Tags: ios, ios7, uinavigationcontroller

So UINavigationController's swipe-to-go-back functionality, that was introduced with iOS 7, has an annoying "snap" at the end of the animation. It's really jarring to me as a user, and I feel like if the animation could be tinkered with, then it might feel a bit better.

An example would be Instagram's update on 12/12/13. They somehow slowed down the swipe-back animation so that it feels much more fluid. Would this require completely custom functionality, or is there a way to hijack UINavigationController's existing functionality? How can this be achieved?

**EDIT**

Okay, so I know that custom transitions are the way to go. However, I'm confused on exactly how to implement them. I've seen references to several delegate methods, but no clear examples of how to achieve custom animations. Could someone provide a basic example, specifically for overriding UINavigationController's push/pop animations?

Comment: See "Supporting Custom Transition Animations" on the UINavigationControllerDelegate - https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UINavigationControllerDelegate/navigationController:animationControllerForOperation:fromViewController:toViewController: there are lots of tutorials and some WWDC videos on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your own interactive transitions to completely customise how they work!

I followed a fairly decent tutorial in the "[iOS 7 By Tutorials](http://www.raywenderlich.com/store/ios-7-by-tutorials)" PDF by Ray Wenderlich.

I've also had a quick google and this might help: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/ios-7-custom-transitions/

Comment: A word of warning - landscape custom transitions are quite broken in iOS7 currently. I suggest either sticking with portrait or waiting for at least iOS7.1 before implementing. More on landscape issues here: http://blog.spacemanlabs.com/2013/11/custom-view-controller-transitions-in-landscape/